# Display total sales for category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter

I'm trying to list the **total amount of product sold** at the top of each category page.

A portion of this total will be donated and my client wants to advertise the amount. I have been looking and trying things for hours now and have not had any luck. I found a plugin that displays total sales for the whole store, but I want just one category.

I tried adding another filter to this plugin, but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need you rephrase and extend your question, and add your current code. It's very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSaleAmountbyCategoryID($product_cat_id)
{
    //first getting all the Product ID by Category ID
    $pro_args = [
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'pages_per_post' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                'terms' => $product_cat_id, //(int)
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $product_ids_query = new WP_Query($pro_args);

    $include_product_id = $product_ids_query->posts;

    //getting all the success orders
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_status' => ['wc-processing', 'wc-completed', 'wc-onhold']
    ];
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $total = 0;

    $orders = $my_query->posts;
    foreach ($orders as $ctr => $value)
    {
        $order_id = $value->ID;
        //getting order object
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        $items = $order->get_items();

        foreach ($items as $item_data)
        {
            $product_id = $item_data['item_meta']['_product_id'][0];
            if (in_array($product_id, $include_product_id))
            {
                //getting product object
                //$_product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                //$qty = $item_data['item_meta']['_qty'][0];
                $pro_price = $item_data['item_meta']['_line_total'][0];
                $total += $pro_price;
            }
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

*Add the ^^above code to your active theme `functions.php`*

**USAGE**
In your product category page template call it like

```
echo getSaleAmountbyCategoryID(21); //replace it by your product caregory ID
```

Please Note: *I won't say this is a best solution as it will be slow if you have 1000s of order. If I find out the better solution I'll update my answer.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: @bigbluehouse: I'm glad that it helps you, but please don't forget to accept my answer as it solve your question.

Comment: I've used it but nothing displayed